# i am creating a pseudocode in determining the largest number among a list of positive numbers entered by a user

Tags: logic

i  am creating a pseudocode in determining the  largest number among a list of positive numbers entered by a user. ALso the user should indicate that he/she has finished enter numbers by entering a 0. Thank you

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
max <-- 0     // assigning max to 0      
n <-- read()  // read user input

while n!=0 
{
  if(n>max)     // check if n is greater than max
     max <-- n  // if true update max

  n <-- read()  // read next input
}

print(max)     // print max
```